# Combine: converting one publisher to another in func

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I'm using the Amplify framework for my auth on the combine framework.

I want to check if the user is currently logged in. This is done by the following function

```
Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession()
```

This returns:

```
AnyPublisher<AuthSession,AuthError>
```

I've put it in a function, so I can call it from my AuthenticationViewModel, which deals with the business login for auth.

```
enum AuthenticationsFunctions {
    static func fetchCurrentAuthSession() -> AnyPublisher<AuthSession, AuthError> {
        Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession().resultPublisher
    }
}
```

For my view model, it has states and events. In the code below, I want to call the authentication function and return the appropriate events. Such as .onAlreadyLoggedIn. Because the auth function returns a different publisher, I can't figure out how to return the appropriate event to AnyPublisher<Event, Never>

AuthSession has a function .isSignedIn which is a boolean.

```
    static func fetchCurrentLogin() -> Feedback<State, Event> {
    Feedback { (state: State) -> AnyPublisher<Event, Never> in
        guard case .loading = state else { return Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher() } //Checks if the state is loading (When the app first opens)
        AuthenticationsFunctions.fetchCurrentAuthSession().allSatisfy { (AuthSession) -> Bool in
            if (AuthSession.isSignedIn) {
                return true
            }
            else {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Amazon on their docs provide this:

```
func fetchCurrentAuthSession() -> AnyCancellable {
    Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession().resultPublisher
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        .sink {
            if case let .failure(authError) = $0 {
                print("Fetch session failed with error \(authError)")
            }
        }
        receiveValue: { session in
            print("Is user signed in - \(session.isSignedIn)")
        }
}
```